# How do I show LoadingController for multiple requests in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

As per the Ionic documentation I could load Ionic LoadingController using this piece of code:

```
ionViewLoaded() {
  let loader = this.loading.create({
    content: 'Getting latest entries...',
  });

  loader.present().then(() => {
    this.someService.getLatestEntries()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.latestEntries = res;
        loader.dismiss();
      });

  });
}
```

This works fine if I am just making 1 ajax request. But I have 5 requests to be made and if I hide / show loading controller like this it leads to flickering of the screens.

Is there a way where I can present the loadingController but then `dismiss()` only when all of the Ajax requests have been completed?

`EDIT:` Requests do not depend upon one another. They are independent. What I am looking for is a way to get notified when all observable's request is completed. That way I could dismiss the LoadingController when all of them complete.

Comment: Where is the 2nd request in your code?

Comment: also note that this does not work fine as you are not waiting for request to complete before calling `dismiss` on the loader...

Comment: Please, add more informations concerning the requests, how are they related to each others ? does one depdend on the other or not ?

Comment: @n00dl3: Good question. No they not depend upon one another. I edited my code to put dismiss inside subscribe. Gabriel's answer is correct but would hurt performance as all asynchronous requests would become synchronous. Does the information now help?

Comment: no, all asynchrnous request won't become synchronous, they will get sent one after the other though.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using following utility in my app. This would also work for multiple steps or/and pages if we want to show the same loader and need to change loader text at different steps.

We can call showLoader() multiple times, would need to ultimately call hideLoader().

```
@Injectable()
export class Utility {
    loader: any = null;
    constructor(private _alertCtrl: AlertController,
        private _loadingController: LoadingController) {
    }

    private showLoadingHandler(message) {
        if (this.loader == null) {
            this.loader = this._loadingController.create({
                content: message
            });
            this.loader.present();
        } else {
            this.loader.data.content = message;
        }
    }

    private hideLoadingHandler() {
        if (this.loader != null) {
            this.loader.dismiss();
            this.loader = null;
        }
    }

    public showLoader(message) {
        this.showLoadingHandler(message);
    }

    public hideLoader() {
        this.hideLoadingHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use multiple subscribe, and if your requests do not depend on each other you can use the `combineLatest` operator, so all requests will execute concurently, and get notified when they have all completed :

```
ionViewLoaded() {
  let loader = this.loading.create({
    content: 'Getting latest entries...',
  });
  let loaded = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.someService.getLastEntries().do((entries) => {
      //do stuff with last entries
    }),
    this.someOtherServices.getOtherStuff().do((stuff) => {
      // do stuff with stuff
    })
    // etc...
  )
  loader.present().then(() => loaded.toPromise()).then(() => loader.dismiss());
}
```

Comment: How about *forkJoin*? http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0 It looks better approach to me because the code is easy to read. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You could chain all the requests inside every subscribe.

```
ionViewLoaded() {
  let loader = this.loading.create({
    content: 'Getting latest entries...',
  });

  loader.present().then(() => {
    this.someService.getLatestEntries1()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.latestEntries1 = res;
        this.someService.getLatestEntries2()
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.latestEntries2 = res;
            // OTHER CALLS ...
            this.someService.getLatestEntries5()
              .subscribe(res => {
                this.latestEntries5 = res;
                loader.dismiss();
              });
          });
      });
  });
}
```

The way you're using the `loader.dismiss()` is not good, it'll call the `someService.getLatestEntries` and imediatelly use the dismiss, you need to use it inside the return of your promise/subscribe/observable so it only dismiss when the function is done.

Don't forget about adding an `onError` with every call, since it's 5 you don't want one to go wrong and then the user get stuck forever. So add it and inside of every `onError` add a `loader.dismiss();`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But this would hurt the performance - wouldn't it? You are nesting all calls so all asynchronous calls would become synchronous now?

Comment: using multiple subscribe is a bad idea